# Is there a way to store instances of own classes in the ApplicationSettings of a Windows Store app?

Tags: configuration, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a Windows Store app I can only store WinRT types in the ApplicationSettings, according to the documentation. For roamed settings that should be held together I can use ApplicationDataCompositeValue. Trying to store an instance of an own class or struct results in an Exception with the message " WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written to the application data store. Additional Information: Data of this type is not supported". The term "trying to serialize" indicates that there must be some way so serialize a type for the application data API.

Does anyone know how I could achieve that?

I tried DataContract serialization but it did not work.

Comment: Did you mark your class as Serializable?

Comment: @Mike Brown: I tried but SerializableAttribute is not available in .NET API for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of this. Looks like you have a viable alternative though :)

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768796/what-is-the-best-way-of-saving-listobject-in-windows-8-app?lq=1 for a solution with Custom type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think custom/own types are not supported.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx: 
"The Windows Runtime data types are supported for app settings."

But you can serialize your objects to XML and save as string... (see code below)

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    using (var sw = new StringWriter()) 
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(sw, obj);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
{
    using (var sw = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(sw);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/blob/master/src/MyToolkit/Serialization/XmlSerialization.cs

Check out this class too:

https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/XmlSerialization

**Disclaimer: The above links are from my project**