# local settings in windows phone 8.1 not letting me assign an object as a value c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I made a class to hold entries of data and when I am trying to assign the class to the local settings value in windows phone 8.1 it keeps throwing a system exception. Here is the code any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
  public static HoursList GetHoursList()
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        HoursList h = (HoursList)localSettings.Values["HoursList"];
        if (h == null)
        {
            localSettings.Values["HoursList"] = new HoursList(); //This is where the exception throws
        }
        return (HoursList)localSettings.Values["HoursList"];
```

Comment: Where's the exception type and message?  I suspect the error has something to do with serialization. ApplicationDataContainer can't contain just any old type. Everything it stores must be serialized to permanent storage.

Comment: @glenebob I thought the ApplicationDataContainer could hold any object, so how would I serialize the object?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. But at the end of the day, you will most likely have to produce a string that you store in the DataContainer, and then you'll have to be able to serialize that back to your HoursList when retrieving. Perhaps JSon would work for this?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768796/what-is-the-best-way-of-saving-listobject-in-windows-8-app/12769232#12769232. It is for Windows 8, but the idea is as @glenebob said, to turn the complex structure into a string and store that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store complex types this way. There are few options how to solve this. If your class HoursList is complex, then you can make it serializable - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

Easiest way would be to let someone else (like Newstonsoft https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) do the serialization and deserializaton work.

If the class is simple enough, you can just build string, include for example ; as a separator and save it. `String.Join()` and `yourString.split()` will help you.